# Linq to sql stop working

Tags: linq-to-sql, submitchanges

hey,
I have strange problem, i've built a prject using the Linq, and most of it works fine,
However sometimes all the Linq's Repository commands stop working, and i'm geeting errors,
the issue solve when i overwrtie the existig dll files of the Linq project?
maybe one bad command hurt the rest to the Datacontext? 
the Question is how can i deal with it?

Thanks,

etc, im getting some kind of errors like the following:
A transport-level error has occurred when sending the request to the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)

Comment: please be more specific, what do you mean by "stop working"? post also the error message.

Comment: stop working means that none of the function in the repository works at all..

Comment: There must be some more error information than just the "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host".

Comment: i think i've found the bad Function! i'm getting the error: "Collection is read-only" when i'm trying to submit changes, how can i know which update cause it and i cant i clear it

Comment: We had an issue with the same symptoms as this, and we solved it by disabling connection pooling in (change to the connectionstring). I don't like it, and I don't understand what caused the problem, but it made it go away.